# How can i remove billing address field in stripe checkout form?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I am using a custom code in WordPress for redirecting to checkout page of stripe but stripe checkout form is showing billing address

```
        var data = { 
          action:'sendpayment', 
          currency:currency,  
          amount:amount,
          payment_method_types:["card"]
        }; 
        jQuery.post(window.location.origin+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {   
          response= JSON.parse(response);  
          if(response.sessionId){ 
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: response.sessionId,
            }).then(handleResult);
          }else{
              handleResult(response);
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify [billing_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-billing_address_collection) as `required` which will only collect it if it's necessary (at Stripe's determination). There is not an option to tell Stripe to never collect it, though.